# std namespace does not support list in Android NDK

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk

When I try to use `std::list` in my project it says symbol "list" could be resolved. I have added the line `APP_STL := stlport_static` in Application.mk and included `list` header. I am using `NDK-r9d`.

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of including `list` header we have to include `stl\_list.h` header. This solved my problem